# "to play" VS "to play in."

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language, phrase-choice

The following sentence is from a tv series (Friends). A friend asks him to play because he says he has made music for some time. And in reply to the request he says in a shy manner:

**I haven't played in so long.**

I looked it up in 3 dictionaries. None included a phrasal verb **"to play in."**

So, why do you think he said **"play in"** instead of **"play"**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> None included a phrasal verb "to play in."

That phrasal verb doesn't exist.

*In X* is a way to express a "X amount of time must pass before Y" or "X amount of time has passed since Y"

> We'll go to the store in five minutes = five minutes must pass before we go to the store.

> I haven't played chess in years = years have passed since I've played chess.

> I haven't played in so long = so long has passed since I've played.

*So long* is an inexact time expression basically equivalent to "a very long time."

(This is an AmE perspective, BrE may be different)

Comment: Thanks. I woud have never imagined it being used in that way.

Answer (score 3):

He didn't. He said "I haven't played **in so long**" (It's been a long time since I last played). A British English speaker would say **for so long.**